# What does $!n$ mean where $n$ is any positive integer?

Tags: combinations, factorial

I know what a factorial is, but I am taking combinatorics now and one of the solutions to a problem contained something like this $!6$, this is the first time I have seen something like this.

What does this mean and how do I evaluate it?

Comment: I don't think it's universally accepted notation, but it usually stands for a [derangement number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)  It satisfies the recursion $!n=(n-1)\left(!(n-1)+!(n-2)\right)$ ($n!$ satisfies the parallel one) but $!0=1,!1=0$ whereas $0!=1=1!$.

Comment: @lulu, thank you, it looked very odd at first. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it because you answered my question?

Comment: Yes, well that's one reason it isn't universally accepted.  I'll post the answer....the site complains if questions go unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's universally accepted notation, but it usually stands for a [derangement number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  Thus $!n$ denotes the number of permutations of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ with no fixed points.

It satisfies the recursion $$!n=(n−1)\left(!(n−1)+!(n−2)\right)$$ ($n!$ satisfies the parallel one but $!0=1,!1=0$ whereas $0!=1=1!$)